# SQL Server Group Records Based Another Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a table that contains employee data. The table has historical employee records based on department and year as follows:

[image]

Now I want to consolidate records based on EmployeeId, Department and get the Min FromYear and Max ToYear like this:

[image]

I tried to use a query :

```
Select EmployeeId, Department, MIN(FromYear), MAX(ToYear)
from Employee
GROUP BY EmployeeId, Department
```

But this query fails for the employee with ID 3 as it returns me only 2 rows:
[image]

I have added a similar structure and query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f1e53/5

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Identify the islands using `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  Then aggregate:

```
select employeeid, department, min(fromyear), max(toyear)
from (select e.*,
             sum(case when prev_toyear >= fromyear - 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by employeeid order by fromyear) as grp
      from (select e.*,
                   lag(toyear) over (partition by employeeid, department order by fromyear) as prev_toyear
            from employee e
           ) e
      ) e
group by employeeid, department, grp
order by employeeid, min(fromyear);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d59184f8f8ae57fa060ddcff311f7e88) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use self join as well

select    a.employeeid,    min(a.fromyear),    max(b.toyear)    from    emp a
inner    join    emp    b    on    a.employeeid=b.employeeid
group    by    a.employeeid